# Counting subquery results SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, subquery, distinct

So the code I have is trying to count the number of ratings given to a movie per state.  That's all easy done.  I also need to count the number of ratings given to award winning movies, per state.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad.state "State",
   COUNT(r.ratingid) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.state) "Number of Ratings",
   COUNT(
          SELECT DISTINCT r.ratingid
          FROM netflix.ratings100 r JOIN netflix.movies_awards a
                 ON r.movieid = a.movieid
              JOIN netflix.addresses ad
                 ON ad.custid = r.custid
          WHERE a.awardid IS NOT NULL
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.state) "Number of Award Winning Movies Rated"
FROM netflix.addresses ad JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
   ON ad.custid = r.custid
JOIN netflix.movies_awards a
   ON r.movieid = a.movieid
GROUP BY "State"
```

The second count statement should be counting the number of ratings made where the awardID is not null. That subquery alone works, and returns distinct ratingIDs, but the thing as a whole does not work.  I get ORA-00936: missing expression.  Solutions?

Comment: Needed: table definitions (column names and data types, just for the columns needed for the query); typical input data in the two tables, and the desired results from that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got brackets around the subquery - you have the brackets to indicate the count, but you need an extra set to indicate that it's a subquery.

E.g;

```
count( (select ....) ) over ...
```

Moreover, you're reusing the aliases from your outer query in your inner query, plus there's nothing to correlate the subquery to your outer query, so I don't think you're going to get the results you're after.

Additionally, you've labelled a column with an identifier that's over 30 characters, so unless you're on 12.2 with the extended identifiers set, you're going to get `ORA-00972: identifier is too long`.

Finally, I don't think you need that subquery at all; I think you can just use a conditional count, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad.state "State",
            COUNT(r.ratingid) over(PARTITION BY ad.state) "Number of Ratings",
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.awardid IS NOT NULL THEN r.ratingid END) over(PARTITION BY ad.state) "Num Award Winning Movies Rated"
FROM   netflix.addresses ad
JOIN   netflix.ratings100 r
ON     ad.custid = r.custid
JOIN   netflix.movies_awards a
ON     r.movieid = a.movieid
GROUP  BY "State";
```

You may not even need that distinct; it depends on your data. Hopefully you can play around with that and get it to work for your requirements.

Comment: I should point out that Gordon's answer is more correct, since you are after an aggregate query (you've got distinct along with your analytic queries, which means you want to collapse the rows. Which is what an aggregate query does.) I was focused more on why your query was failing than looking at it overall, unlike Gordon. *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a complicated query.  This should be an aggregation query . . . with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ad.state, COUNT(DISTINCT r.ratingId) as num_rated,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.awardId IS NOT NULL THEN r.ratingid END) as num_rated_with_award
FROM netflix.addresses ad JOIN
     netflix.ratings100 r
     ON ad.custid = r.custid LEFT JOIN 
     netflix.movies_awards a
     ON r.movieid = a.movieid
GROUP BY ad.state;
```

Notes:

- There is no reason to give a column an alias equivalent to its original name.  So, `as "State"` is unnecessary, unless you really care about capitalization.
- A movie could have more than one award, so to get the number of ratings, use `count(distinct)`.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.
- The query has no need of window functions.